# In ASP.Net MVC Code First, Is the manual foreign key atribute required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, relational-database, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

When I'm creating a relationship between two POCO classes using Code First, I can just create a reference from one class to another. for example.

```
class Student{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Full_name {get;set;}
    public Department dept {get;set;} // Navigation property
    // public int DepartmentId {get;set;} // 
    // there is automatically DepartmentId column created by Code First Migration
}

class Department{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Dept_name {get;set;}
}
```

The Code First migration will create a DepartmentId Column to store the propper foreign key.

Is the manual creation of the foreign key property required, of best prectice, for some reason?